# Is there a way to make a Pie Chart with iTextsharp?

Tags: itext

I need to make a Pie Chart for a new PDF document I'm developing but I haven't found a way to make it happen. As long as I've been researching there's no obvious way to draw a piece of a pie chart. just a full circle witch doesn't help.

My goal is to have a pie chart where each piece can be independent and have different size and radius.

I've tried to use circles and divide the circle with lines but it would be better if I could draw each piece of the pie chart independently, so i could make the design more appealing.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll need to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help get traction on your question.